# angularjs route won't scroll if ng-view is attached to element inside body in bootstrap application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, ng-view

However, if ng-view is attached to the body tag itself, the scrolling issue doesn't happen.

I have been working on an application using bootstrap for months and have never had any scrolling issues until I added a (bootstrap)  into  and moved ng-view onto a  inside .

Now, certain routes just don't scroll - but only sometimes.  And they do scroll upon page refresh.

I don't see anything in angular's documentation restricting ng-view to the body tag, so that can't be it.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was actually that if I opened a bootstrap modal on one page (route), clicked a link inside the modal, and navigated to another route, the modal never got destroyed.  Bootstrap's JS put a class on the body tag  that set overflow to hidden.  So on the page I navigated to by clicking the link in the modal, the body was frozen and the page was not scrollable.  It didn't have anything to do with ng-view.  I was simply making some alterations in the overall architecture at the same time as implementing the modals, so it got confusing.

I was trying to use a Bootstrap modal inside an angularJS application.  It's much better to use something like UI-Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, but I don't have enough rep to comment so here goes.

Angular tries to keep the scrolling position when changing routes. Try adding this to you ng-view and see if it helps. `data-autoscroll="true"`

Comment: hi @jdpipkin, I've resolved that issue a long time ago.  Thanks for reminding me because I can put up the answer now, although it's mostly just me being stupid...